# Will PC3-10600 1333Mhz RAM work in a Laptop that has PC3-12800 1600?

Tags: laptop, memory

I have a lenovo y40-80 laptop that comes with 8.0GB PC3-12800 DDR3L 1600 MHz installed.  I have an old laptop with another 8GB chip of PC3-10600 1333Mhz DDR3.  If I added the PC3-10600 to the lenovo would it work?

Answer (score 1):

If BIOS settings are left on auto-detect, yes, it will work, but both modules will use the lower speed (1333Mhz).